# Do JComboBoxes have a maximum number of fields?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I had a look through the documentation but could not find an answer to this... Obviously, it becomes impractical to use a JComboBox if the number of fields becomes too high, but all the same, in theory, do JComboBoxes have a maximum number of fields?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Create a loop and keep adding options

Comment: What do methods like `setSelectedIndex(...)` take as a parameter?

Comment: @camickr Good point, one could then assume the limit to be INTEGER.MAX_VALUE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods like `setSelectedIndex(...)` and `getItemAt(...)` take an `int` variable as a parameter. This would indicate that the `ComboBoxModel` can support a "theoretical" maximum of INTEGER.MAX_VALUE items.

However, the items must also be rendered and ultimately displayed in a JScrollPane. The scroll pane and vertical JScrollBar also use an `int` variable to specify the pixel location of the scrollbar.

So you must also consider the height of each rendered item in the scroll pane.

Therefore a more reasonable "theoretical" maximum using the standard Swing components would be INTEGER.MAX_VALUE / rendered-row-height.

However, I suppose you could create a custom scroll pane that only displayed the items in blocks. So as you scroll towards the end of one block you preload the next block. Theoretically this would allow you to display all INTEGER.MAX_VALUE items in the combo box.

I don't know if there would be any other limitations for the "theoretical" maximum number of items.

In any case I'm sure we all agree a combo box would become unusable well before the "theoretical" maximum is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Not to my knowledge, like you said it might become more useful to use another interface tool if you end up having to scroll for too much. My reasoning is because you can dynamically populate it which needs to be as flexible as your data.

Comment: Yes, there is  limit, see my comment. The combo box would be impractical to use well before reaching this limit.

Comment: I disagree, the method you referenced is setting within an index of (n). Meaning that the index count is as many as you have in the combobox. Unless I misunderstand the question which is does each index have a limit.

Comment: The question is "how many items can you add to a combo box"? If you don't like my first example method then how about the `getItemAt(...)` method? So the "theoretical" limit is controlled by the largest index you can use to access an item directly.

Comment: The theoretical limit is probably much smaller than INTEGER.MAX_VALUE, depending on how the UI draws the list. If it is like a JList in a scrolled window, the Y position of the nth item has to fit in an int, leading to a max of something like (INTEGER.MAX_VALUE / fontHeight)

Comment: @camickr who controls the largest index that can be accessed.

Comment: Java does via the API and the definition of what an "int" value is. And as FredK has mentioned the limit would be even smaller due to limitations of rendering the components in the scroll pane.

Comment: Now that I see your response, I see that I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: @camickr I suggest summarizing all you said in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer @camickr gave you, I created an array with the hightest integer value in java (INTEGER.MAX_VALUE, which is 2147483647) and then after waiting for ten seconds the program throwed me an ***Requested array size exceeds VM limim*** error. According to plumbr.io that means:

> Java has got a limit on the maximum array size your program can
> allocate. The exact limit is platform-specific but is generally
> somewhere between 1 and 2.1 billion elements.

Then I decided to try just with 1.800.000 elements and that worked, it lasts 10 secs approximately and when I clicked the combo box it took like 5 seconds to load all the elements, but it worked with no issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30099003)